# Windows 7 PPTP VPN can ping and HTTP to servers but not Windows Explorer

Tags: vpn, pptp

I just started working from home connecting to the office network over PPTP VPN (I'm using Windows 7 Pro). I have my hosts file set up with the internal IPs of all the servers I need to connect to within the network (file & web servers).

When on the VPN I can ping any of the servers by name or IP, I can use MSTSC to connect to them, and I can get HTTP traffic too. However, I cannot access file shares in Windows Explorer either by name or IP (most servers run WS2003) - the error is 'network path not found'.

In many forums I see the suggestion to disable 'use remote default gateway' in the VPN connection properties, but this wipes out all network access - I can't ping other machines or access the internet.

At first I thought I had an IP clash - my home router gives me 192.168.1...., machines that are physically in the office network are like 192.168.0...., and my VPN IP is 192.168.1.... However after changing my router's IP range to give 192.168.2.... nothing changed.

Any advice on this would be much appreciated as I rather like working from home!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a firewall on you PC?  Can you disable it and try?

Comment: Yes it's depressing but this was the answer. I went straight past the firewall when trying to figure this one out because it seemed so ridiculous that it would be the problem. Make this #2 on the list of stupid things that AVG firewall does by default (#1 was blocking all outbound VPN connections)